# Origen y significado de «Aprovecha gaviota que no hay otra»

Tags: significado, modismos

Encontré este frase en un libro para estudiantes de español:

> Aprovecha gaviota que no hay otra.

La traducción a inglés es:

> Here is your chance!

¿Por qué?

¿Cuál es el origen del frase?

Comment: Yo la conocía como "Aprovéchate gaviota que no te verás en otra".

Answer (score 9):

Es simplemente una rima. Se suele decir "no hay otra (oportunidad)" o "no te verás en otra (situación igual)". Y para que la frase quede graciosa y rime, llamas al interlocutor gaviota. Por cierto, rima en *asonante*, solo las vocales.

Este tipo de frases son de la cultura popular de cada región y se suelen decir en lugar de una frase más plana y aburrida. Cuando usas una frase de este tipo en esta situación, das más razones para que esa persona aproveche su oportunidad, no es solo tu opinión, también lo dice el saber popular.